# python gspread rounding large numbers

Tags: python, gspread

I am using gspread to append/update rows in a Spreadsheet. currently I am running the following:

```py
spreadsheet = gc.open_by_key("UNIQUEKEYFROMGOOGLE").get_worksheet(1)

Name = "Logic"
Status = "Active"
ID = 692458977690124339

newlist = [
    Name,
    Status,
    ID,
]

spreadsheet.append_row(newlist, value_input_option='USER_ENTERED')
```

Expected new line in the google spreadsheet is:
Logic, Active, 692458977690124339

Actual new line in the google spreadsheet is:
Logic, Active, 692458977690124000

How can I make sure it doesn't round the large ID number to the nearest thousandth?

I've already tried value_input_option='RAW' and this just puts the last entry as 6.92459E+17

Comment: I think as with many other systems this gspread uses `float64` or `int64` to represent numbers. It means that it is limited to around 10^15-10^19. One way to solve your task is to store number as string, try doing `ID = str(ID)` before adding to list, does it solve your task?

Comment: Yeah, I figured it might be something like that, I've been finding rows with numbers that long and when I threw the number into a variable and printed it out, it did not limit it so I hoped I was just doing something wrong. Thankfully converting it to a string worked perfectly fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think as with many other systems this gspread uses float64 or int64 to represent numbers.

It means that it is limited to around 10^15-10^19 values. And you have bigger-precision numbers.

One way to solve your task is to store number as string, try doing `ID = str(ID)` before adding to list, does it solve your task?